# What is the complexity of 2 loops with the inside loop starting at the first ones actual index?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, complexity-theory

people of the internet,

I am studying algorithms and their complexity and I wrote a "naive" code for finding the number of inversions in an Array. First, it seemed easy and then I started wondering if that j=i+i changes the second loop's complexity from O(n) in a worst-case scenario to something lower ?

Here is my code written in java :

```
public static void naiveInversionCount(int[] T){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < T.length -1; i++){ // O(n)
        for(int j = i+1; j < T.length; j++){ // O(n) ???
            if(T[i]> T[j]) count++; // O(1)
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Naive method returns : " + count);
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: It will be O(n^2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer loop runs exactly *n* times.

The inner loop runs *n*−1, *n*−2, …, 0 times per outer loop. That is, on average, *n*/2 times.

And `count++` runs exactly once per loop.

Thus the nested loop runs 1·*n*(*n*/2) times, which is in (*n*²).